# Round to 2 decimal places in Java using DecimalFormat

Tags: java, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I am using DecimalFormat to round a value(in Double type) to 2 decimal places

```
var decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
return decimalFormat.format(value);
```

When value = 50.275 => result is 50.27
As expected, the result should be 50.28
I have tried using RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN as well but it didn't work either.

Comment: Do you have `50.275` as a String or a `double`?

Comment: It’s a Double one

Comment: Required reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and 
[Is Floating Point Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/18157)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`50.275` cannot be represented exactly and the actual floating point value is something like `50.274999`. Thus it is rounded down.

If you have `50.275` as a `String`, you can create a `BigDecimal` out of it and format that.

```java
new BigDecimal("50.275").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toPlainString();
// 50.28
```

Comment: I see, will try it and get back later. Thank you. @@